# Dplyr::filter works on data frame but not on vector, why is this?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, filter

I have used dplyr:filter on a data frame to get all the numbers not divisible by 3 and 2, but this function did not work on a vector. I am curious as to why this is so?

Here is my code:

```
vec<-vector()

for (i in 1:1260){
  if (i %% 2 !=0){
    vec<-c(vec,i)
  }
}

vec<-data.frame(vec)
vec%>%filter(vec%%3!=0)
```

Comment: Well, `dplyr::filter()` should be applied on data frames. Look at the `.data` parameter in the specification.

Comment: Without transforming `vec` to dataframe try this from `magritt` `vec %>%extract(.%%3!=0)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
vec<-vector()

for (i in 1:1260){
  if (i %% 2 !=0){
    vec<-c(vec,i)
  }
}

vec<-data.frame(vec)
answer <- vec%>%filter(vec%%3!=0)
real_answer <- answer$vec
```

The problem is that `filter` is meant to work with dataframes

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation here it seems like only the use with a tibble/tbl is correct and you are lucky that your data.frame works: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/filter

This seems to be part of a general understanding that tidy data is data in data.frames.

In R data are often used in vectors and if `a` and `b` are vectors of data you can just plot them using

```
plot(a, b)
```

where there is an implicit connection of the value of `a[n]` and the value of `b[n]` being connected via a common `n`. However, there is always a risk of that implicit connection being disturbed when changing `a` or `b` alone. There is less risk if the connection is made explicit within a data.frame or a tibble where values in the same row belong together.

If, e. g. you do `na.omit(a)` there is no telling which `a` value belongs to which `b` value, whereas a `na.omit(data.frame(a, b))` is save in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `data.frame`, you can try

```
vec[vec%%3!=0]
```

or

```
subset(vec,vec%%3!=0)
```